# Selecting the next input of an event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have (an array of) two inputs `product` and `category`.

The product one is an autocomplete.
I would like to fill in the category when a product is selected.

the problem that the `event.target` is not a `jquery` object, so it seems I can't apply the jQquery's `.next("input")`

Here is my code:

```
var addedProduct = $(".produit:last > input");
addedProduct.autocomplete( {
        source: Object.keys(availableProducts),
        select: function(event, ui){
            var category = event.target.next("input"); // something like this ???
            category.value = availableProducts[ui.item.value]; //{"product1":"category1",...}
        }
    })
```

The inputs location is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new jQuery object from the event target with `$(event.target)`. You'll be able to call `.next` on it afterwards

The other solution without jQuery is to use the native DOM API. You can select the next element with [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling). The only requirement is that the element you want to target **must be immediately** the next element.

**EDIT**: From the DOM structure provided you can use `.parent().next()` to select the next element at the parent level. Then on this new element use `.find()` to select the wanted input. Note that the code is highly tied to the DOM structure. You could use the `id` to directly select the element.

```
$(event.target).parent().next().find("input");
```

Comment: thanks for the second suggestion. unfirtunately is not the immediately next one...

Comment: I added the inputs location in the OP, it seems `next("input")` doesn't work either

Comment: I've updated my answer to match the provided DOM structure.