# How do I search for the next element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How should I search for the next element (say, input) starting from a given one (they are not immediate next siblings)

I the following example ([codepen here](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/PXgYvm?editors=1011)) I need to set a "categ" value having initially the "prod" one.

From "prod" i should search for a next "input":

```js
$("input.categ").val("cat");
$("input.prod").next("input").val("dog");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input class="prod"></li>
  <li><input class="categ">I need "dog" value here</li> 
</ul>
```

**The real case**

Imagine an array of products and their categories. Once the user changes a product, the category should change accordingly to the selected product:

```
[prod 1][categ 1]
[prod 2][categ 2]
...
[prod X][categ X]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is because `next()` looks for sibling elements, yet the `input` elements are not siblings.

To do what you need through DOM traversal you would need to get the closest parent `li` from the `.prod` input, then use `next()` to get the sibling `li`, then `find()` to get the `.categ` input, like this:

```js
$("input.categ").val("cat");
$("input.prod").closest('li').next('li').find("input").val("dog");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input class="prod"></li>
  <li><input class="categ">I need "dog" value here</li> 
</ul>
```

You should note that in this case DOM traversal is rather moot, as you could just select the `$('.categ')` element directly, but I assume this is a learning exercise.

Comment: suppose I don't know the DOM structure, I just know that is the next "input" if i read the HTML from top to bottom...

Comment: You can't traverse the DOM without knowing its structure - any attempt to do so would be pure guesswork. The order of the HTML is not relevant, you're traversing the DOM nodes which is a tree, hence you need to go up/down/sideways as needed.

Comment: you selected "closest" that matched a parent "li", not a sibling... maybe there are something similar methods...

Comment: That's the only workable solution given your HTML. There are methods to select siblings but they are not relevant to your HTML as neither of your `input` elements have siblings, hence there is nothing to be selected.

Comment: I updated the OP in order that the example be more clear... this is not a learning exercice...

Comment: This logic still works for that case, although it would be much more useful if you showed the HTML itself instead of some pseudo code.

Comment: the given answer is better to be universal, to use to other people, not just for my exact case...

Comment: if interested, is linked with the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214830/selecting-the-next-input-of-an-event-target/54214900?noredirect=1#comment95257229_54214900

Comment: This logic is universal, you just don't seem to be understanding it.

Comment: The previous question you've linked to is even telling you the same thing I am - and the HTML there is completely different to what you've shown above.

Comment: the provided answer there is working as well for this speudo code: `$("input.prod").parent().next().find("input").val("dog");` so "more universal"

Comment: That's actually less universal as `parent()` requires the `li` to be the explicit parent of the `.prod` element. The example I showed uses `closest()` so the `li` can be at any level above the `.prod`.

Comment: In any case the approach is the same (get parent, get sibling, find input, update value) so I'm not sure what the issue you now have is.

Comment: I agree with your last comment... the approach is the same... I thought there is a universal way in Jquery to fing following elements...

Comment: Fair point. So what exactly is the problem? You're been given the same approach in two answers now, and now we're at the bottom of a chain of worthless comments for seemingly no good reason.